# Basic URL Django Issue

Tags: django

This basic url issue is giving me a headache. I have two links I wish to take a fictitious user to: localhost/prediction and localhost/prediction/. The first works, the second doesn't with an error saying that the site doesn't exist. Any clue as to why?

URl Patterns:

```
urlpatterns = [
    # ex: /prediction/
    url(r'^', views.post_list),
    # ex: /prediction/<number>/
    url(r'^(?P<number>[0-9]+)/$', views.show_body)
]
```

View:

```
def show_body(request, number):
    return HttpResponse(number)
```

Comment: Have you tried `r'^/?'`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change your pattern from

```
url(r'^', views.post_list),
```

to

```
url(r'^$', views.post_list),
```

There's no need to add a leading slash, because every URL has that. See [the example in the Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/urls/#example).